# OpenCV: face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) not working

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def face_finding(img_name, img_path):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    #eye_casecade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

    realimg = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.resize(realimg, dsize=(500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow("img",img) ##for dbg

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(gray) ##for dbg

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    print(faces) ##for dbg

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]

        cv2.imwrite(str(img_name), cropped)
        print('image save')

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

img size is about 1~1.5MB
cv2.show(img) show well and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRJwG.png)

no error occur but faces gonna be empty...
i replace xml file and test again, but still same happen

Comment: try `lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml`

Comment: Aside from trying different classifiers for detection, you can also tweak the function parameters. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498

Comment: Does it work on different images like lena.png?

Comment: lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml->  OpenCV face recognition error (-215) !empty() in function                    lena.png also dosen't work T-T

Comment: i dont know why, this is worked at faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 3)  maybe function parameters is problem

Comment: It worked. Nothing wrong with ur code.